# How do I convert my code to a list expression

Tags: python, list

My code:

```
line = input().split(';')
for i in range(len(line)):
    row = []
    for num in line[i].split(','):
        if int(num) >= 1000000000:
            row.append(num)
    print(','.join(row))
```

I need to output numbers greater than 1 billion in a special order

input:

> 150000,10000000000;2000000000,1345678910,330000000

output:

> 10000000000
>       2000000000,1345678910

How do I convert my code to a list expression, without using for-loop outside the expression

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python list comprehension tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: strange, I tried it but couldn't find anything

Comment: When I do the search, the first 16 hits are appropriate tutorials.

Comment: How does 200000000 get printed since its a digit less then your if criteria

Comment: How does the given input provide 2 lines of output?

Comment: my bad 2000000000*

Comment: about 2 lines of output. the line is separated by the symbol";", a group of numbers separated by this sign on different lines

Comment: Are you trying to print the section (delimited by ";") if any number is greater than 1 billion?

Comment: a list comprehension is not always the answer, not everything thats in for loops can be written as list comprehensions. for example you can make a list of all the numbers greater than your condition with a list comprehension `[num for line in data.split(';') for num in line.split(',') if int(num) >= 1000000000]` but this will give you a list with 3 results, you will lose the context of which line they came from so wont be able to know to print 1 entry on one line and two entry on the next. your for loops are perfectly readable, no need to replace with a comprehension

Comment: Of course you can do a one-liner like `print('\n'.join(','.join(num for num in line.split(',') if int(num) >= 1000000000) for line in input().split(';')))`, but that's not very readable.

Answer (score 2):

I have understood your code to basically print only numbers greater than 1 billion in each semicolon-delimited list. So without any *explicit* for loops, I see the code as the following:

```
def big_numbers(line):
    return ",".join(filter(lambda num: int(num) >= 1_000_000_000, line.split(',')))
print("\n".join(map(big_numbers, input().split(';'))))
```

---

Is the same as:

```
def big_numbers(line):
    condition = lambda num: int(num) >= 1_000_000_000
    filtered = filter(condition, line.split(','))
    return ",".join(filtered)
inp = input().split(';')
rows = map(big_numbers, inp)
print("\n".join(rows))
```

---

So that your input of `150000,10000000000;2000000000,1345678910,330000000`
yields :

> 10000000000
>       2000000000,1345678910

---

You can even make it more verbose by changing the lambda function into an actual function, but this is equivalent, and subject to your developer bias. :)